# Angular - How to run the application on partner's host domain

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cross-domain

I'm creating an app based on Ionic 6 Capacitor 3 Angular 12.
In my code I use links to assets starting from root like "/assets/img/img.png" everywhere.
Now the web app should be placed on the partner's website in exotic way: index.html should be inserted in html of partner's website.

So I have all my assets and scripts on **https://example.com**

And index.html is on **https://partnersdomain.com/page-of-our-website**

The major problem is I should not change Base Href tag to

```
<base href="https://example.com/"/>
```

coz Base Tag belongs to partners website. They use it for their's needs.
I also should not change the address of the partner's page, That is why I added to all navigation methods:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/some-page', { skipLocationChange: true });
```

So to create local base href for my environment I added baseHref to Angular.json

```
"build": {
  "options": {
     "baseHref": "https://example.com",
```

The assets are loading well from needed domain. But now I got Unhandled navigation error.
[image]

I also tried to add base href in app Module this way:
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'https://example.com/'}

Please help me to find solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please describe a problem? You said *This works well. So to create local base href for my environment I added baseHref to Angular.json*. I don't know whats not working?

Comment: I edited. Thank you. I meant avoiding of url changes is working well.
The problem is I have navigation error when I add baseHref property to Angular's config.

Comment: did you try `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { baseHref: 'https://example.com' })`? Here you can add `baseHref` dynamically as well (like by getting the value from backend from `APP_INITIALIZER`)

Comment: There is no baseHref property in ExtraOptions interface of forRoot(). I tried to add this to app.module in Providers: {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: 'https://example.com/'} The same error.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean `APP_BASE_HREF ` only.

Comment: So no, it doesn't help. But if I change base tag in html - it will work. But I should not change it.

Comment: you can do the same while doing `ng build -=production --base-href="https://example.com/"`

Comment: I think the this attribute jsut add value to base tag in index.html. But I use custom index as I described.